# How to send Javascript map as a parameter from lightning component to Apex server controller?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex

I have a salesforce lightning component which enqueues server side action. To that action I need to pass a map as one of the parameters, but it looks like it takes memory address of the object instead.

The client side code that creates the map and calls the server side action:

```
var action = cmp.get("c.save");
var mapToSend = new Map()
for (var key of valueMap.keys()) {
    mapToSend.set(key, valueMap.get(key))
}
action.setParams({
    "name": cmp.get("v.name"),
    "params": mapToSend
});
```

In the controller then:

```
 public static Boolean save(String name, Map<String, Object> params) {
```

log of the javascript shows nice `Map` with all the correct fields, but salesforce system log shows just

```
14:55:16.0 (3172304)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[41]|name|String|false|false
14:55:16.0 (3188041)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[41]|name|"Account"
14:55:16.0 (3191758)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[41]|params|Map<String,ANY>|true|false
14:55:16.0 (3204719)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[41]|params|{}|0x30d2397a
```

Any Idea why? What those `|false|false` and  `|true|false` mean in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with understanding the javascript data structures. The correct result is achieved by calling the apex controller with data prepared as

```
var mapToSend = {}
for (var key of valueMap.keys()) {
    mapToSend[key] = valueMap.get(key);
}
action.setParams({
    "name": cmp.get("v.name"),
    "params": mapToSend
});
```